# Can the 'level' act as the noun?

Tags: verbs, nouns

Source:https://www.google.co.in/?gfe_rd=cr&ei=DLBOV__9BurI8Af4oq_YCw#q=dead+heat+meaning

> A situation in which two or more competitors in a race are exactly level.

Shouldn't it be 'leveled'?

Comment: It's an adjective; [meaning 2](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/level_2).

Comment: What do you mean exactly? "Level" can be noun, verb, adverb, and adjective. All you need is to look it up. Here is a link to help you http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/level

Comment: *Level* is an adjective here. And as an adjective, it can be modified by an adverb such as *exactly* or *very*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*To be* and a few other words including *to seem*, *to become* are a type of verb called a *[copular](http://www.englishgrammar.org/copular-verbs/)*.  Adjectives can follow copulars.

Comment: Where's the use of copulars in above?